# Bus error : 10 in data generation in C

Tags: c

This is my definition of a Edge.

```
typedef struct Edge{
    int first;
    int second;
}Edge;
```

In my main I'm trying to generate a set of random edges and write them into an array.

```
int main(){

const int NUM_VERTICES = 1024;
const int NUM_EDGES = 1024;

Edge* edges[NUM_EDGES];

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EDGES; ++i)   
    {
        edges[i]->first = (rand() % (NUM_VERTICES+1));
        edges[i]->second = (rand() % (NUM_VERTICES+1));
    }
    printf("Reached here");
    printf("Data Set: ");


    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EDGES; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d -> %d", edges[i]->first, edges[i]->second);
        printf(((i % 4) != 3) ? "\t":"\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

When I run this  program, I get a

```
Bus error : 10
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: And where do you allocate the `Edge`s??

Comment: I'm not doing a explicit malloc, wouldn't an implicit allocation work. Since the scope of the edges array is only inside the main function.

Comment: And who do you thinkwould do that implicit allocation?? You have an array of **pointers**! I suspect you have some missconception about arrays, pointers, `struct`s and definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array `edges` is uninitialized. So you can't deference its elements. This [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You don't really seem to need an array of pointers. So just use an array:

```
Edge* edges[NUM_EDGES];
```

to

```
Edge edges[NUM_EDGES];
```

and change the `->` to `.` operator everywhere in your code.